# How to permanently disable a kernel module (kvm-intel) in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

Every time I start, I have to manually do "sudo modprobe -r kvm-intel" for VirtualBox to be able to use hardware virtualization facilities. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blacklist the offending kernel module:

```
vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Add a line such as "blacklist kvm-intel"

This is assuming that VirtualBox doesn't want to use the kernel module either.

Comment: Putting it in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` will mean you have to deal with conflicts whenever Debian/Ubuntu update their blacklist - better to keep it in a separate file to avoid having to merge the changes each time you upgrade packages etc.

Answer (score 9):

`echo "blacklist kvm-intel" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-local.conf`

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It seems that a new line is required at the end of the file in order to get this to work for me (Ubuntu server 12.04)